# Attach DIV to the side of another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've searched this website, as well as w3schools trying to answer this for myself, and unfortunately I have not.

If you take a look at this page on my website (http://theust.net/characters.php) and scroll down, you will see two DIVs pop out with images in them.

Using CSS and moving the DIVs to the right locations, I was able to get them around the exact location I want them to appear, the problem I have is that they only look like that on 1920x1080 displays, and if you have any other resolution, they end up in random locations.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to fix or anchor them to the DIV they are next to, without putting them inside a container DIV.

(The source code is not hidden, and should be viewable. Just in case, I've included it below.)

```css
/*
This is the stylesheet for the overall website.
*/

.site {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

h2 {
    text-align: right;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px;
    width: 60%;
}

.hcontent {
    position: relative;
    top: 6.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: #fff;
}

.content p {
    color: #888;
    font-style: italic;
}

.content p::first-letter {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #090909;
}

h3.open, h3.closed {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #999;
}

h3.open {
    text-align: left;
}

h3.closed {
    text-align: right;
}

h3.who-quote {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #999;
    text-align: right;
    font-style: italic;
}

h2.over-h2 {
    text-align: right;
}

h4 {
    text-align: right;
}

/* Specific Content Page CSS */
.anchor {
    display: block;
    height: 110px; /*same height as header*/
    margin-top: -110px; /*same height as header*/
    visibility: hidden;
}

.Div1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 6.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: #fff;
}

.Div2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 8.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: #fff;
}

.Div3 {
    position: relative;
    top: 10.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: #fff;
}

.Div4 {
    position: relative;
    top: 12.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: #fff;
}

.Div5 {
    position: relative;
    top: 14.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: #fff;
}

.Div6 {
    position: relative;
    top: 16.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: #fff;
}

/* Side Divs */
.Div1-Side1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 180px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
    bottom: 20em;
    left: 20em;
    z-index: 10;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.Div2-Side1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 180px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
    bottom: 1.2em;
    left: 94.6em;
    z-index: -1;
    visibility: visible;
    display: none;
}

.Div2-Side2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 180px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
    bottom: -14.8em;
    left: 94.6em;
    z-index: -1;
    visibility: visible;
    display: none;
}

/* Side Div Content */
.Div2-Side1 span {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.Div2-Side2 span {
    font-size: 10px;
}

/* h3 Links */
.content p a:link, h3 a:link {
    color: #888;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.content p a:visited, h3 a:visited {
    color: #888;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.content p a:active, h3 a:active {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.content p a:hover, h3 a:hover {
    color: #555;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
 .Div1-Side1 {
 display: none;
 visibility: hidden;
 }
}
```

```html
  <div class="over-content">
  <div class="Div1">
  <span class="anchor" id="HOverview"></span>
    <h2 class="over-h2">Overview</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="Div2">
    <span class="anchor" id="HPoliChar"></span>
    <h2 class="over-h2">Political Characters</h2>
    <h4 class="char-names" id="Leo-Char">Leonard H. McCoy</h4>
    <p>
      Little is known about the life of Leonard McCoy before he entered politics, however, what we do know is that he is not fully human. He is a cyborg, and while some cyborgs age as humans do, the only part of Leonard McCoy that is human is his brain, which is constantly monitored and maintained by his many on-board systems, which keeps it in perfect condition.
    </p>
    <p>
      From what we can gather, before he was a Cyborg he had a loving Wife and three children. From what\'s left of the reports, all we know is a tragedy befell them, and the only survivor was Leonard. After year\'s in a Hospital, the doctors realized the only part of him not dead or damaged was his brain. In what can only be considered the birth of a new race, they recreated his body with robotics and put his brain into it.
    </p>
    <p>
      Now, many centuries later, He is still the President of the United Stars of Trekys. Unwilling to not continue to run for President, he has won the last elections dating back all the way to the fall of our dictatorship. For the last fifty years, he has run under his own third party and continuously wins!
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h4 class="char-names">Conrad K. Leopold</h4>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>
    
  <div class="Div3">
    <span class="anchor" id="HMiliChar"></span>
    <h2 class="over-h2">Military Characters</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="Div4">
    <span class="anchor" id="HMiscChar"></span>
    <h2 class="over-h2">Misc. Characters</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae erat ipsum. Aenean eu cursus tortor, id laoreet diam. Donec sodales et ante eu varius. Praesent a risus eu tellus condimentum sagittis. Mauris volutpat elit mauris, vitae placerat tellus euismod sit amet. Duis at nibh vel magna condimentum mattis vitae sit amet metus. In laoreet convallis semper. Suspendisse viverra elit gravida felis interdum, nec aliquam orci efficitur.
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="Div1-Side1">
    Test
  </div>

  <div class="Div2-Side1">
    <img src="images/Leonard-McCoy.jpg" alt="Leonard H McCoy" height="135px" width="101.25">
    <br>
    <span>
      <b>Age:</b> 675
      <br>
      <b>Race:</b> Cyborg
      <br>
      <b>Occupation:</b> President
    </span>
  </div>
      
  <div class="Div2-Side2">
    <img src="images/Leonard-McCoy.jpg" alt="Leonard H McCoy" height="135px" width="101.25">
    <br>
    <span>
      <b>Age:</b> 65
      <br>
      <b>Race:</b> Human
      <br>
      <b>Occupation:</b> Vice-President
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you did not choose bootstrap?

Comment: Your markup placement sure is messing the page. You should consider to wrap each contents as you'd want to show their layout on your page. Or just use bootstrap like @GobSmack said, It'd help your page alot

Answer (score 0):

For fix them to the right side of the DIV they are next to, just set `left: 100%` to `.Div2-Side1` and `.Div2-Side2`, also set `position: relative` to the content in your case `.over-content`, on the other hand if you don't want putting them into a container I'm afraid you have to vertical position it manually for example:

```
.Div2-Side1{
    top: 800px;
}

.Div2-Side2{
    top: 1040px;
}
```